# Java Model Status - Cannot nest inside

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

My Visual Studio Code IDE shows me this error during a Maven build:

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core 4 1 2019-07-31 12:58:13.130
!MESSAGE Failed to add classpath entry for generated source folder annotations
!STACK 1Java Model Exception: Java Model Status [Cannot nest '.../target/generated-sources/annotations' inside '.../target/generated-sources'. To enable the nesting exclude 'annotations/' from '.../target/generated-sources']
```

A notification appears at the bottom right of the screen showing:

```
Build failed, do you want to continue?
```

I can click on the `Proceed` button and the build completes successfully.

The environment versions:

```
Version: 1.36.1
Commit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529
Date: 2019-07-08T22:55:08.091Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.0.0-050000-generic snap
```

Here is the `.classpath` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry excluding="target/generated-sources/annotations/" kind="src" path=""/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="target/generated-sources/annotations">
    <attributes>
      <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
  </classpathentry>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

There are a lot of them, like one per sub directory. If I delete all of them, VSCode will recreate them all.

I suspect the `Language Support for Java(TM)` extension by Red Hat to be the one [creating these files](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/618).

Comment: could you show your .classPath file ?

Comment: Where can I find this file ?

Comment: There's a ton of such `.classpath` files (lowercase) in the project.

Comment: yes, .classpath,could you show it ?